# Как сделать динамический вывод в label?

Tags: c++, qt

Пишу программу на с++ и мне надо сделать так чтобы текст в лейбле менялся динамически. Тоесть как пример:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50;i++) {
 ui->label->setNum(i);
 }
```

но естественно в такой программе ничего работать не будет, тоесть после нажатия просто сразу выводит 49. А как сделать так что бы я видел как это меняется ? "1..2..3....45"?
Пробовал такие вещи как label->repaint и label->update,но ничего не помогло.

Comment: Вы сами то понимаете что хотите сделать? Из вопроса кажется что вы хотите сделать задержку между итерациями цикла, но при этом пробуете абсолютно несвязанные вещи. Так что вы все таки хотите сделать?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch да, я хочу видеть как это меняется, что бы было типо как таймер

Comment: и как, по вашему в этом должны помочь repaint и update?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch думал это будет каждый раз их перерисовывать или что то типо того, если бы я знал как это работает не спрашивал бы тут

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch можете помочь?

Comment: а теперь пораскиньте мозгами немного: с какой скоростью выполняется цикл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно создать таймер. Грубый пример может выглядеть примерно так

```
#include <QTimer>

QtTestApp::QtTestApp(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &QtTestApp::on_clicked);
}

void QtTestApp::on_clicked()
{
    static int counter = 0;
    QTimer* timer = new QTimer;
    QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this, timer]() {
        ui.label->setNum(counter);
        counter++;
        if (counter > 50)
            timer->deleteLater();
    });
    timer->start(1000);
}
```

Я здесь использовал лямбду (безымянную функцию) для обработчика событий от таймера, но обычно под обработчик создают слот в одном из объектов (который так же владеет и таймером и счетчиком) и цепляются к слоту.

Comment: неа, не работает пишет много ошибок

Comment: Ну так это грубый пример а не финальное решение. В порядке исключения я добавил полностью рабочую программу (Qt 5.12), но вообще Вам надо учиться самостоятельно разбираться в возникающих проблемах и уж как минимум задавать адресные вопросы (много ошибок? каких конкретно? какая из них Вам непонятна и т.д.)